# StringEscapeUtils find out if string is escaped

Tags: java, string, escaping, apache-commons

I've been using StringEscapeUtils.escapeHTML to escape URLs. Is there something similar to find out if the string is already escaped?

Comment: How do you decide a String is already escaped or not?

Comment: No haven't seen that. An ugly workaround could be to unescape and check for diff (in length...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I know of, but it is pretty easy to do one yourself:

```
public boolean isEscaped(String url) {
    return !url.equals(StringEscapeUtils.unEscapeHTML(url));
}
```

Note that deciding if a random string is escaped or not is impossible as @themel notes, you can get a lot of false positives if you try this with random strings. However I'm assuming that you at least have some control over what your strings look like here.

Comment: Yeah I've got it down to: StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(href)) it just seems rather silly to unescape sth to escape it afterwords Every time :p

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible in principle, since every escaped string is at the same time an unescaped string, e.g. `"a&gt;b"` could be both an escaped version of `"a>b"`  or simply the literal string `"a&gt;b"` before escaping.

Comment: And `&gt;` can be escaped as `&amp;gt;` which can be escaped as `&amp;amp;gt;` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to escape any string until you get pure HTML tags try this recursive method:

```
    public static String unescapeHtml(String string) {
    if (org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank(string)) {
        return "";
    }
    String unescapedString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(string);
    return string.equals(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(string)) ? unescapedString : unescapeHtml(unescapedString);
}
```