# Determine if there is/are escape character(s) in string

Tags: java, string, escaping

Let say I have

```
String str="hello\" world\\";
```

when printing `str`, the output is

```
hello" world\
```

even when printing `str.length()` the output is

```
13
```

Is there any way to prove that `str` value has escape character(s)?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Just curiosity

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran - Special character != Escape Character.

Comment: Not really sure if its possible, but [this seems to be a good read](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12260872/2024761).

Comment: @Christian I don't know how to explain _'why'_, but just curious if it is possible

Comment: Can check link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327355/is-there-a-java-function-which-parses-escaped-characters

Comment: I am thinking that whenever we print a `string` and the output contains character such as `"` and \, then  we can conclude that those character, `"` and \ was escaped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as escape characters at run time.

Escape characters appear only in String literals. For example,

```
String literal = "Some\nEscape\rSequence\\\"";
```

At compilation time, the compiler produces a `String` value with their actual binary representation (`UTF-8` iirc). The JVM uses that `String` value directly.

You wrote

> I am thinking that whenever we print a string and the output contains
>   character such as " and `\`, then we can conclude that those character,
>   " and `\` was escaped?

This is not true, those characters might have been read from a file or some other `InputStream`. They were definitely not escaped in a text file.

Comment: so means we cannot determine if the characters is escaped or not?

Comment: @DnR Not at run time, no. And why would you want to?

Comment: nothing much important. just want to show that `hello" world\ ` is actually `hello\" world\\ `

Comment: @DnR That's only true, if that `String` came from a `String` literal and there is no way, at runtime, to guarantee that.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

Use the Apache Commons Library, specifically [StringEscapeUtils#escapeJava](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava-java.lang.String-).

```
jshell> StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("Newline \n here \u0344 and unicode \f\n\r\t\"\0\13 and more")
$136 ==> "Newline \\n here \\u0344 and unicode \\f\\n\\r\\t\\\"\\u0000\\u000B and more"
```

This prepends a backslash to each escape sequence and also swaps the variable-width octal sequences for fixed-width Unicode sequences. This means that every escape sequence will consist of "\\" two backslashes, followed by one of {n, b, r, t, f, ", \}, *or* a 'u' character, plus exactly four hexadecimal [0-F] digits.

If you just want to know whether or not the original String contains escape sequences, search for "\\" in the Apache-fied string. If you want to find the positions of those sequences, it's a bit more involved.

See more at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/awwsmm/b1707beead1adba391214b50fbd4a794).